# pq factorization

Tags: ds.algorithms, nt.number-theory, factoring, primes

If I tried to factor a semiprime as the product of the two prime factors given below in the form pq on a home computer would I be successful?

p=(2^1024-1)+644  prime factor
q=(2^1028-1)+188 prime factor

thanks for the replies

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Feed it with this semiprime: 253630045503841601190019425078101873844891259427547116272721 and let us know the result.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer but ok.          366843387617597212562794266547, 691385081658413817748016689643                     can i have an answer now?

Comment: @user68942: forget it, I thought you made a fast program for factoring so my intent was to give a hard to factor semiprime, but completely missed its size (it should be 1024 digits long)

Comment: I was waiting for someone to answer to ask the right question about factoring.
the first question was a provocation to get an answer from a person capable of factoring large numbers. I ask now. Are you able to factor this semiprime in a short time?
102871258271817087746588121936639673713684691781048528382987839424506956640621905621689594929571101784228432009538937742027037369152353064318406162591788964666631606887709372155070888201286038306802082382484546985661473351057 I am able to factor it in a short time. If your answer is positive then you have answered my question. On the contrary, if it

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Maybe you should see this and probably yes, it's a new factorization program that factorizes what other factorization programs don't factorize. https://youtu.be/gjED9D4gkfI

Answer (score 2):

Hart's [one-line factorization algorithm](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/54707/1/WRAP_Hart_S1446788712000146a.pdf) can do it in 150 microseconds with my unoptimized implementation (in [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)):

```
olf(n,iter)=for(i=1,iter,my(s=sqrtint(n*i-1)+1,m=s^2%n,t);if(issquare(m,&t),return(gcd(n,s-t))))
olf((2^1024+643)*(2^1028+187), 100)
```

Comment: You can cut the time in half by using the variant in section 3 of the paper.

Comment: https://youtu.be/J-XxkA2WhXk

Answer (score -2):

yes, it can be done and in a very short time.

follow these steps and you will have the answer you are looking for

I show you how:

p=(2^1024-1)+644

q=(2^1028-1)+188

N=pq

X=998737

C=719077253944926363091722076315609893447190791576922629093720324630930703222003852530833909289630144084480455519485573430635159075257666489971389722557896497511071573699461941105208878404984376477812331808340023075352602729369851525895652442163308948653402042738345192959788983753918865219341425318496895550173

A=N Mod(C)

B=N-A

Mcd(A+CX,B-CX)=p

I await comments

Comment: C = 2^1026 - 998691 = 2^1026 - X + 46

Comment: I can’t make any sense whatsoever of either the question or this answer. Are you claiming that this is a general semiprime factoring algorithm? If yes, where did the magic constants X and C come from? If not, then what’s the point? Surely if the goal is just to give a sequence of instructions that will compute factors of the specific number $((2^{1024}-1)+644)((2^{1028}-1)+188)$, the easiest way is `print 2^1024+643, 2^1028+187`?

Comment: I can't answer you here because my answer is too long. So I added an answer to my question